# React Native Firebase messaging background notification doesn't open app

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I added firebase push notifications to my app.js file as following:

```
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

async function registerAppWithFCM() {
  await messaging().registerDeviceForRemoteMessages();
}

//inside app function:
const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log("Foreground message");
})

messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});
```

Then i sent a notification from the server while app in foreground and it worked (logged "Foreground message"),
when i tried it again while app on the background the notification have arrived and logged (Message handled in the background! and the remote message) but
when clicked on it to open app it crashed the app (App has stopped),
i am using :

"@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.4.0",
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.0",

Comment: it can help if you dump a log of the crash also here so we can know what kind of problem is

Comment: Hi, Did you get solution for this

Answer (score 1):

```
messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
      console.log(
        'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
        remoteMessage.notification,
      );
      navigation.navigate(remoteMessage.data.type);
    });

    // Check whether an initial notification is available
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(remoteMessage => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          console.log(
            'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
            remoteMessage.notification,
          );
          setInitialRoute(remoteMessage.data.type); // e.g. "Settings"
        }
        setLoading(false);
      });
```

Use this notification listeners

https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications

Comment: How did you displayed if app is in foreground state on `onMessage(){ }`?

Comment: If App Is In Active State And You Want To Display Notification InSide Application, Then You Have To Use https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

Comment: localNotification